# copying text with numbering from word to notepad

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad

I need to copy text from microsoft word to notepad and keep the numbering
e.g in word

1. hi
2. hello
3. something else

and i'll need the exact same thing to appear in notepad(which i have saved i utf8 format). problem is it works for some word files but does not work for most word files. any help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying and pasting, click **Save As**, and select **Plain Text** as the file type. The .txt file that's generated will include the numbering from the Word doc and should open in Notepad by default (unless you've changed some settings) when you double-click it.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the document as a PDF, the Word auto-numbering will be converted to fixed numbers. Open the PDF and copy text from that.

Note, though, that PDF files have line-breaks at the end of each line, so set the page-width in the Word document as wide as you wish to avoid the extra breaks.